# How to properly specialize a templatized static const member that is the same type as its parent

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

If the title isn't clear, the code should help clarify:

```
// .h file    
template<class T> class DF_Vector3
{
public:

    T x, y, z;

    static const DF_Vector3 ZERO;

    DF_Vector3() {}
    DF_Vector3( T F );
    DF_Vector3( T X, T Y, T Z );
};

typedef DF_Vector3<DF_FLOAT> DF_Vector3F;

// .cpp file
template<> const DF_Vector3F DF_Vector3F::ZERO( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); // ERROR: Explicit specialization of 'ZERO' after instantiation
```

The compiler subsequently cites another location where DF_Vector3F::ZERO is referenced and states: "Implicit instantiation first required here."

The Visual Studio 2010 compiler doesn't seem to mind this.  However, Apple's CLANG (LLVM) compiler does not like it (it's the one complaining).

Is there a way to fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `typedef` in the definition of the static members, because by the time you have a `typedef`, the class template is already instantiated, after which you cannot explicity specialized its member(s).

You should do this:

```
//general case
template<class T> 
const DF_Vector3<T> DF_Vector3<T>::ZERO;

//specialization
template<> 
const DF_Vector3<DF_FLOAT> DF_Vector3<DF_FLOAT>::ZERO(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

//after that define the typedef
typedef DF_Vector3<DF_FLOAT> DF_Vector3F; //after
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/AMWMC

Comment: While this solution did eliminate the compiler error, I'm now getting duplicate symbol link errors.  If this example code is included in a header file, it will cause ZERO to be defined multiple times--once for each .cpp file it ultimately gets included in. It would be nice to be able to access these constants using the shortened typedef-ed version of the class name.  As far as I can tell, the specialization needs to reside in a single .cpp file in order for it not to be duplicated.  Am I missing something or is there simply no way around this? Thanks.

Comment: @BrianLawson - did you ever solve this? I'm curios to know how you handles "duplicate symbol" error.