# avoiding multiply-defined symbols when specializing a templatized static const member

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am encountering a problem very similar to the topic addressed here:
[How to properly specialize a templatized static const member that is the same type as its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637589/how-to-properly-specialize-a-templatized-static-const-member-that-is-the-same-ty)

Here's my code:

```
template <class T>
class p3d
{
public:
    p3d() {
        x = 0;
    }

    p3d(const T &_x) {
        x = _x;
    }

    static const p3d<T> origin;

    T x;
};

typedef p3d<float> p3df;

int main(int, char**)
{
    p3df p = p3df::origin;
    return 0;
}

// elsewhere in a *.cpp file
template<> const p3df p3df::origin(0.0f);
```

When compiled under a strict compiler like Clang, I get the following error:

```
explicit specialization of 'origin' after instantiation
template<> const p3df p3df::origin(0.0f); -> implicit instantiation first required here
```

The solution is to move

```
template<> const p3df p3df::origin(0.0f);
```

to be before the typedef.  The problem with this solution is that it results in multiply-defined symbols, because now `p3df::origin` is defined in every file that uses the vector header.  Is there any way to properly specialize the static const typedef-ed templates, while avoiding duplicate definitions in all source files using the typedef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the line

```
template<> const p3df p3df::origin(0.0f);
```

before the `main()` function, but after the `typedef`.

I am really not sure what the problem is here. It seems like clang complains that you're providing a definition for the template specialization *after* using said specialization. gcc/4.9 (nightly build) does not have an issue with it.

Generally speaking, having a static template definition in a header file is cool, since they are - as the name implies - templates. However, if you specialize your template, thereby making it an actual class, the one definition rule applies as to any regular class, and you need to move the definition to a non-header file.

Comment: I agree that moving the template earlier works when the code all lives in a single file. But because there will be multiple source files including the header for the p3d class, that also means that there will be multiple instances of "template<> const p3df p3df::origin(0.0f);", and when linking, Clang (and most other compilers) will then fail due to multiply-defined symbols.